# Why is there Rails.rb files all over the place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Was digging around my Rails applications and noticed that there are rails.rb files all over the place. In my ruby gems directories like:

```
...gems\devise-2.0.4\lib\devise\rails.rb
...gems\cucumber-rails-1.3.0\lib\cucumber\rails.rb
...gems\railties-3.2.3\lib\rails.rb
```

I am assuming that there are executed whenever you issue some command like "rails xxx". So all these extra rails.rb files combine with the original rails.rb file to essentially make one big rails.rb file. Essentially, when we type in "rails xxx" it goes thru all them all?

Just looking for some confirmation PLUS a little more knowledge about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to understand what these `rails.rb` files are doing, is to read the source code.

- [ralties](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb)
- [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails.rb)
- [cucumber-rails](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/lib/cucumber/rails.rb)

As you can see, in any library the file assumes a different scope. The common behaviour is that the file `rails.rb` normally contains the code required to initialize the library when loaded from a Rails project.

BTW, this has nothing to do with the script/rails command and there is no "big rails.rb" file.

Answer (score 1):

The files are not generated but are simply source files of these libraries you are using.

In this case they are probably rails-related classes that either extend Rails in some way or modify it or make the library interact with Rails.

Rails is a very common framework in Ruby land so most if not all libraries will have some sort of integration with Rails.

By no means are all of those loaded when you run `rails XXX` but rather when your application loads these libraries their rails.rb files may be executed to provide some sort of integration with Rails.